# What aftermarket batteries for Fujifilm FinePix X100?

Tags: battery, generic-brand, third-party, fujifilm

I want to get a spare battery for my Fujifilm FinePix X100. It takes the Fuji NP-95 rechargeable battery. These are very hard to find; aftermarket brands are much more common. I'm hesitant to put an off-brand battery in a $1000 camera, though.

Does anyone (a) have a recommendation for a brand that they have personally tested with an X100, (b) know of a brand/store that guarantees no damage to the camera, or (c) know of a source of genuine Fuji batteries?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've written an article about this very thing, http://www.x100enthusiasts.com/discussion/80/batteries-chargers-power-management-finepix-x100-user-guide

I've been using a MaxPower brand generic for 5 weeks now without issue. Other users have reported similar experiences in the comments.